# Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool' [

Tags: c#

```
public static bool isValid(int num)
{
    bool status = true;
    int digit, rev = 0, ck_num; // Added new variable
    ck_num = num; // Assigned it to variable num

    // Tests for palindrome
    while (num)
    {
        digit = num % 10;
        num /= 10;
        rev = rev * 10 + digit;
    }

    if (rev == ck_num) // Checked it against unchanged variable
        status = true;
    else
        status = false;
    return status;
}
```

I've set the public static bool isValid parameter to (int num) but it still says that the type int cannot be converted to bool. Can someone help me with the fix?

Comment: The problem is `while (num)`. `num` is not a bool. What's the condition it needs to be? `num > x, num < y` , etc. Fix it.

Comment: `while (num)` => while requires `bool` condition to stop the loop, and you need to include condition returning `bool` like `rev < num`.

Answer (score 2):

In the while loop, you have to provide a condition(bool) so that the loop continues until the condition is met. You have instead provided an int instead of a condition(bool),so while(num) is giving you an error. Just change it to while(num!=0) and that should give you a fix.